# JQuery: How to force a select option to be "selected", using FancySelect plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a direct **question**: How to make "selected" an option of a select using FancySelect plugin?

This is the **situation**: I have a select with two options and two links. The links should be synchronized with the select. That means that when clicking on a link, it must make "selected" an option of the select.

It is important notice anyway that it is not a normal select, but i am using a JQuery plugin called **FancySelect**: http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/
And this can be the main reason why normal solutions found elsewhere in StackOverflow did not apply to my specific case.
So the point is not how to make "selected" an option of a select, but how to make it "selected" while using the FancySelect plugin.

Here you can understand better:

http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/11/edit

This is the **code** i am trying to use, but is not working yet:

```
$( "#a1" ).click(function() {

     $("#selector option:first").attr('selected','selected');
 });
```

Can you tell me please how can i force an option of a select to be "selected"?
Thank you very much!

Comment: For changing _properties_ use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of the `attr`.

Comment: You are using some plugin try, `$("#selector").val("1").trigger('change');` http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/12/edit

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's of great importance to this question that you're using something that's **not** just an ordinary `<select>` element.

Comment: @PSL Thank you very much! Please write it as an answer and i will check it. I have also edited the question adding the specification that in this case i was using the plugin called FancySelect

Comment: hi here your jsbin corrected and working http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/21/

Comment: Thank you. If you write as an asnwer, i can mark as correct!

Comment: Nobody will be able to post an answer until the question is reopened. Since you did not mention the usage of a plugin, it sounded like a duplicate question and it has been marked as duplicate. I have voted to reopen though.

Comment: Ok, will try to change a bit and be more specific

Comment: And by the way, instead of adding a click handler to each link it's better to add 1 click handler to parent, like: $( "#second" ).click(function(e) {
  var val = $(e.target).data('value');
  $("#selector").val(val);
});

Comment: Ok, thank you @PSL, to reopened the question. Hope the editing was more specific now. At this point your answer can be the correct one since it the shortest and, as already tested, it can apply to different situations (also when do not have a link but for example a Google Map polyline)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are using a select plugin. So generally they convert the underlying `select` to divs/spans etc to achieve good look and feel. And hence when you change the select option you need to notify the plugin saying that you have updated it. In this case it seems like you can trigger a `change/update` event to do so. You need to do the same thing (triggering an `update`) when you add options dynamically to the select as well, so that the plugin gets updated.

So try:

```
$( "#a1" ).click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#selector").val("1").trigger('change');
});
```

According to the plugin code as shown below, it updates the text while change is triggered.

```
sel.on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
      return e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      return updateTriggerText();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, you don't need any option tag

```
 $("#selector").val("myVal");
```

Comment: It means i have to use: $("#selector").val("1");  right?
But somehow is still now working